# iPerf3 client download comes back with really slow results when tested on a long fat pipe for my FreeBSD server

Tags: networking, freebsd, internet, network-attached-storage

So I operate FreeBSD server that is connected to a 300 Mbps symmetrical fiber line.  It often has to serve users on a different continent so the tested ping is anywhere from 100 to 300 ms, and in extreme cases 625 ms.

With worst case latency (625ms) I calculated that my Window size should be 18.75 MB.  So I set my `kern.ipc.maxsockbuf` to 39321600 and both my `net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_max` and my `net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_max` to 19660800.  But it didn't help much it's still very slow on arrival.  I also tried enabling `net.inet.tcp.path_mtu_discovery` and it seemed to help a little, but with the server pushing into a 300 Mbps uplink, I'm only receiving about 12 Mbps when the download speeds are closer to 50 Mbps.

Am I missing anything, and what else can I do to optimize the server for the large pipe it's handling?  Moving the server is not an option.

Comment: can you share the command line that you're using for iperf?  If you're doing this with UDP, the behavior is strange.  If it is TCP, this is expected, as TCP has issues with windowing on high latency links.

Comment: It is a TCP transfer ```iperf3 -w 4M --get-server-output -c <host> -R```.  The window size of 4M is as high as the Mac will allow but in this instance the latency is only 100 ms so it should be fine.

Comment: Can you figure out the end-to-end MTU?  Perhaps you can't transmit 1500 bytes in a packet, and you end up with fragmented packets.

Comment: @TheCompWiz that's the thing.  I have net.inet.tcp.path_mtu_discovery enabled which basically sets the MTU to the lowest in the pipeline.